# Approach on how to delete records from ODI Target table on conditional basis(Where condition). ODI12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a scenario in ODI 12c where i need to delete the records from target table on a where condition.

SQL Interpretation of ODI Logic:

delete from target table where intergation_table.column <> target_table.column .

is it possible to do in ODI 12c if yes please help me with a solution.

Comment: Please add examples so I can understand your question better. Seems that you want to delete data which is not in the source table. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this is mentioned below, ODI doesn't provide the conditional delete of data based upon source selection so we can modify the KM step to achieve this , Mark the column with user defined flag and use it in the KM , Column name in I$ would be same as target so we can use the same code <%=odiRef.getTargetColList("", "T.[COL_NAME]", ", ", "\n", "UD1")%> in both target and I$ tables:

DELETE FROM <%=odiRef.getTable("L","TARG_NAME","A")%> T
WHERE <%=odiRef.getTargetColList("", "T.[COL_NAME]", ", ", "\n", "UD1")%> 
IN
(
SELECT <%=odiRef.getTargetColList("", "[COL_NAME]", ", ", "\n", "UD1")%>
FROM <%=odiRef.getTable("L","INT_NAME","A")%>)